# Spring Security - Prevent login if missing role

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I have a spring application which uses LDAP authentication to authenticate users, combine this with a custom authority populator I can login to my application correctly. However I want to prevent users from logging in entirely if they don't have a specific role.

I've attempted to create a login success handler which will get the roles from the `Authentication` object and `setAuthenticated(false)` if they don't meet the requirements but this appears to be too late and still allows the user to proceed.

I could create a custom authentication provider but due to the `LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer` being so useful I'm not wanting to do that if possible.

I currently have the security configured with this:

```
auth.ldapAuthentication()
        .userSearchBase(ldapBase)
        .userSearchFilter(ldapFilter)
        .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(new AuthorityPopulator(client))
        .contextSource(contextSource());
```

And my success handler:

```
protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
    String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(request, response);
    List<String> roles = authentication.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList());
    if(!roles.contains("admin")) {
        authentication.setAuthenticated(false);
    }

    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
}
```

Comment: have you created an AccessDeniedHandler? You security configuration can use this method too: "accessDeniedHandler(new AccessDeniedHandler());"